# CSS pinned up menu bar covered by jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I have pinned up/sticky navigation menu bar on top of my page and some tables. To make tables more interactive I use jQuery's [DataTables](http://datatables.net). Before using jQuery everything was OK. Now, whenever I scroll down every table covers my menu and I can't even click on it for navigation.

Here is my pinned up/sticky navigation menu bar code, thank you for your help in advance.

```
CSS:
.sticky     { position: fixed; height: 2.2em; width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgb(224,224,224); }
.sticky li  { display: inline-block; }
.sticky *   { display: inline; }

HTML:
<div class="sticky">
   <reportname>reportname</reportname>
   <ul>
       fly to:
       <li> <a href=#Samples>    Samples    </a> </li>
       <li> <a href=#Navigation> Navigation </a> </li>
       <li> <a href=#Tables>     Tables     </a> </li>
       <li> <a href=#Plots>      Plots      </a> </li>
   </ul>
   <reporthead>reporthead</reporthead>
</div>
```

For tables I use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<script>        
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable();
} );
</script>
```

and

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

Comment: Solved by:
    z-index: 9999;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding

```
z-index: 9999;
```

to the

```
.sticky { ... }
```